# Why does jquery stop after asp.net mvc custom routing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Asp .Net MVC Web application which has a lot of Jquery used. In order to make urls user-friendly, I amended custom routing of urls  using Global asax. Now the custom routing is working fine but the Jquery actions have stopped working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: may be path of jquery is not correct .. check in view source of your rendered page .

Comment: check error of js as well

Comment: @rahularyansharma it's strange that after i apply custom routing, even though you can see rendered js in source , but no action calls.

Comment: give complete url or give cdn  url of jquery ... and try .?